# What happens with my local account when I switch to Microsoft Account?

Tags: skype, windows-10-preview, microsoft-account, microsoft-surface-pro-3

My computer nags all the time on me signing in using Microsoft Account. I've chosen not to do that but e.g. Skype (the modern app) requests that before it starts up. I want to keep using my local, old school login procedure and I want to use my pre-existing Skype account.

What will happen if I tell my computer that it can log in using Microsoft Account? Will the old login procedure still work or will it be expunged and substituted for **only** Microsoft Account?

Please note that I'm running Win 10 opn a Surface 3 (if it's of any significance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your settings and files are kept, and in case there's any annoyance for you with the logon process or anything else, you're completely free to change back to a local account after you try to do whatever you want with the Microsoft account.

Just open the `Settings` app. The `Accounts` tab will let you connect or disconnect it at any time. [These screenshots are for Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/a/716122/33758), but the steps are still the same after you get to the computer settings.

PS: You can install the old-style [Skype for Desktop](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/) for a non-"Please use your Microsoft account for everything" experience.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer his question.

Comment: @Chipperyman How so? He was afraid to play with it because he thought he could lose something. He won't lose anything by trying it out by himself (as per Super User guidelines).

If he or anybody else wants, you can connect your account and add the result of the logging process to my answer.