# Windows 10 Enterprise | Convert an MS account to a local one

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

I want to convert a microsoft connected windows account to a local one on Windows 10 Enterprise.
I've already talked with microsoft's support about the issue and they responded that it's impossible to do so, an answer I haven't quite accepted. So I'm wondering, is there a way? What if I delete my MS account? Would that delink it from my windows account?

EDIT: I know the process is rather simple usually, but the regular "Disconnect" / "Convert to local account" buttons seem to not exist.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/PxExc]

EDIT: The device is not connected to any domain and, as far as I am aware, I should have full control over it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disconnect Microsoft account from my local account](https://superuser.com/questions/716107/disconnect-microsoft-account-from-my-local-account).  Process is similar enough that this counts as a duplicate

Comment: @Ramhound
This is windows 10, while the process for Windows 10 **Home** is similar to the one in the thread you linked, I am using Windows 10 **Enterprise** where the "Disconnect" button is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I understand your using Windows 10 Enterprise.  If this PC is connected to a domain then you might not have the permissions to create a local user account.  I promise you typically the ability to disconnect and create a local account is there on Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: @Ramhound It is not connected to any domain, I should have full authority over the device.

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1703, OS Build 15063.483

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I could not solve it without creating a new account.
The account was probably corrupted in some way?