# How to change users windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I got a new laptop and gave my dad my old one but he never changed the user so now he logs in using my password on my user. The problem is any changes I make to my laptop reflect on to his. I'd just like to peacefully change my wallpaper. Both laptops run windows 10.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The simplest way is to logout of the profile.  This will allow you to select which user you want to log into.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention he's been using it for a while so I'd like to be able to change the user while still keeping all of his data.

Comment: **User data is not deleted if you log out of the profile.**  If you mean you want to transfer the data, then get yourself a storage device, and transfer the files to the new profile.

Comment: "The problem is any changes I make to my laptop reflect on to his. " - Disconnect the profile from your Microsoft Account.

Comment: @Ramhound although logging out will work, he is obviously looking at the option to convert the microsoft account back into a local account.

Comment: @LPChip - It was not obvious at first.  The question is literally "how do I change users" which indicates he wants to log into a different profile not disconnect Microsoft Account from the local account that exists on the device itself.  Of course I have an answer already written for just this situation though.

Comment: @Ramhound it was to me, hence I posted an answer almost immediately after reading the question.

Comment: [I like pretty screenshots personally.](https://superuser.com/questions/716107/disconnect-microsoft-account-from-my-local-account) perhaps you should add some.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you login using a Microsoft Account.

Either let him login using his own Microsoft account, or if he doesn't have one or you want to keep the settings intact, on his (your old) laptop, convert the account back into a normal account.

You can do this by going to settings: Accounts, Other People, Click your account, change account type.