# Convert another microsoft account to local account when logged as administrator

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, user-accounts

I'm logged as the "administrator" on the windows 8.1 machine.
Another account is "microsoft_user" (an Online Microsoft account).

There are similar questions:
[Disconnect Microsoft account from my local account](https://superuser.com/questions/716107/disconnect-microsoft-account-from-my-local-account)
but answers require to be logged as the microsoft_user and knowing this account password.
Is there a way to convert this account without a password?

Comment: You can't reset the password of a linked account as the built-in Administrator.  You will have to reset the password to the Microsoft Account that is linked to "microsoft user".

Answer (score 0):

You may remove a Microsoft account from your computer,
but that would mean that the whole user would be removed with its data.

I suggest :

1. Create a local account for the user
2. Transfer all data from the Microsoft account to the local one,
   and set the local account as owner of the data
3. Delete the Microsoft account from the computer.

For the last step, see the article
[3 Ways to Remove Microsoft Account from Windows 10](https://www.top-password.com/blog/3-ways-to-remove-microsoft-account-from-windows-10/).

If you don't care about the user's data, skip step 2.