# Disconnect Microsoft account from my local account in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, user-accounts, microsoft-account

I have a local account called 'user'.

I gave another person laptop to do some work and they logged into their microsoft account in Edge.

Now their Ms account has tied itself to my local account

Is there any way to untie and remove any traces of Ms account?

"manage" leads to login in Edge - I fear if I ask the person to login again it will take over something more.

[image: Email & accounts view]

A view from another local user - clearly still a local account, but the picture is from Ms account
[image: Other users view]

I found a question about same situation in win8 & win10 and there was a "disconnect" button. [Disconnect Microsoft account from my local account](https://superuser.com/questions/716107/disconnect-microsoft-account-from-my-local-account) But cannot find such option in Windows 11

Comment: Your current situation cannot be solved without the assistance of the owner of the MS Account. The owner of that account has to delete your machine from their account.

Comment: are new local accounts tied to the MS account as well?

Comment: @Albin - No; That is what the second screenshot illustrates

Comment: ok, so "the other user" was logged in under the "user" account?!

Comment: yes - at all times a local account was used on the laptop.


I created another local "user2" account to check if I can untie Ms account from another user. 


I will try the @Ramhound suggestion (login MS account and remove connected machine) and then report here

Comment: @ArmandP Might be a good idea, not to give admin rights to other users on your laptop. At the very least create a guest account. That might have event prevented it.

Answer (score 1):

The MS account user logged in their account and removed my laptop from a list of connected computers. After restart the MS account dissapeared from my Email & accounts view.

Thank you @Ramhound for the suggestion.